# How to give inactive background effect like in UIAlertView, iOS?

Tags: ios, loading

I want to make the view inactive and dim like the effect in the UIAlertView, given below, i want to happen when there is loading the json from url. There will be a avtivity indicator moving in the center.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, really. Try something like the following example. Be sure to add this as a subview below all other views.

```
UIView * modalBackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bound];
[modalBackground setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
[modalBackground setAlpha: 0.5];
```

Comment: Nice trick! But adding behind other subviews is hiding this modal view. It will be handy if someone is trying to show frozen screen using this.